# How can I ungroup each and every button using small size icons on taskbar in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, taskbar

Is there any way by which I can ungroup all icons even if they belong to the same application?

I want to ungroup some of the Windows Explorer files from each other which are grouped together by default.
Note: The question is not about **"Combining" or "Never Combining"**. It is about **"Grouping" or "Ungrouping"**.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [7 Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker).

[image]

It lets you define grouping and non-grouping on a per application basis.

Answer (score -1):

If you set task bar icons to "never combine", then they will never be grouped together.

Grouping icons together, and combining icons together means the same thing.

Why do you say:

> It is not about "Combining" or "Never Combining"