# Windows rearranging icons on taskbar

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I have Windows 8, but I'm sure I saw this option in windows 7 before. I set the Taskbar to combine only when full.

But it seems to me that Windows is once in a while moving the position of the windows within an application on the taskbar. If I try to drag one individual button(icon) for a window of an app on the taskbar, all the buttons(icons) for the windows of that app drag. So I see no way to manually re-arrange.

Am I imagining things or is windows occasionally moving the windows around within the application on the taskbar? This confuses me as I don't know which icon represents which window.

How can I prevent this behaviour so that they are all in fixed positions?

Comment: Right-click and "pin" them so they don't move?

Comment: What your referring to is called Grouping. The terms used are somewhat confusing,a person would think uncombining would solve this but it does not.  http://superuser.com/questions/133320/how-can-i-ungroup-each-and-every-button-using-small-size-icons-on-taskbar-in-win?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Click "Pin this program to TaskBar" - It wont move next time

[image]

Comment: it's already pinned.. but I think nobody knows about the answer to this because it might be that specific application rearranging the windows when I change the workspace in the application.

Answer (score 0):

question should be deleted because now I know it is probably a specific application, not windows, (see my comment under the screenshot answer) causing this behaviour.. and probably this question will just confuse people googling and waste their time reading it.

Comment: You can delete your question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're talking about is a "feature" of Windows. I too use the "combine when full". The new style is not designed for that properly, so it exhibits the moving behavior.

For example, because programs are grouped it may look like this on the taskbar (for pinned apps).

> Search Icon - Internet Explorer - File Explorer - Chrome

Now, ideally, this would serve like the old "quick launch" taskbar where an opened app jumps to the right (over everything). In the new way, it adds any open windows to its immediate right.

Example:

> Search Icon - Internet Explorer - IE instance 2 - IE instance 3 - File Explorer - FE instance 2 - Chrome

This will effectively "slide" your icons right for apps not opened. It does this because when you don't use "combine when full" or "never combine" they show as boxes (for touch users) and a small graphic is added to show there's multiple windows open for that program.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen what you’re talking about (on Windows 7),
and, FWIW, none of the other answers seem to know what you’re talking about. 
I’ve seen this primarily with browsers,
but also Windows Explorer, Microsoft Office applications, and sometimes others. 
It seems to happen when a window “gets sick” (as in “[Not responding]” mode). 
A taskbar button will disappear,
and then reappear at the right end of its group, as if it were a newly created window.

No, I don’t know how to prevent it, control it, or recover from it.

Comment: haha well it's no wonder, I barely understand what I was talking about - but I guess it was annoying at the time )